# Why does this UITableViewController dismiss modally?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a `UITableViewController` that, when presented from one screen, is presented with the standard 'show' segue from right to left, and when presented from another screen (a `UIViewController`), is presented modally from the bottom. I got this to work properly with the help I got from a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819772/how-do-i-segue-to-one-uiviewcontroller-from-multiple-uiviewcontrollers-embedded) I asked a few months ago (has screenshots).

The key was creating the segue from the `UINavigationController` of my Settings screen to the shared `UITableViewController` instead of creating it from the `UITableViewCell`. Strangely though, even though it presents correctly from right to left, dismissing it closes it modally (top to bottom).

I'm making the presenting table view controller a delegate of the `UITableViewController` it's presenting so it will handle the dismissal. Here's the protocol and extension it implements (Swift 2.3):

```
protocol DismissalDelegate : class {
    func selectionDidFinish(controller: UIViewController)
}

extension DismissalDelegate where Self: UIViewController {
    func selectionDidFinish(viewController: UIViewController) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And I set it in the segue defined in the presenting controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToLifts" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! LiftSelectionTableViewController
        destination.dismissalDelegate = self
    } else {
        return
    }
}
```

The presented table view controller calls `delegate?.selectionDidFinish(self)` when the user makes a selection (in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`):

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        guard (dismissalDelegate != nil ) else {
            return
        }
        dismissalDelegate?.selectionDidFinish(self)
    }
```

That calls this method in the presenting table view controller:

```
func selectionDidFinish(controller: LiftSelectionTableViewController) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I've looked through the [APIs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller) for presenting view controllers and haven't been able to find anything that exposes options to control this. The `dismiss(animated:completion:)` API even says it's for dismissing a view controller presented modally, but I don't see anything else having to do with dismissal.

How can I get this thing to dismiss the same way it's presented when it's presented from my `UITableViewController` (right to left, and back) but keep the modal behavior when presented from the other view (a `UIViewController`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused here, it looks like you are using the delegate because the presenting view controller should know how `LiftSelectionTableViewController` got presented.

So in the table view controller, you would have

```
func selectionDidFinish(viewController: UIViewController) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

In the other view controller, you should have

```
func selectionDidFinish(viewController: UIViewController) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

If I'm wrong and you can't know how the view controller was presented, then I would try checking to see if the top view controller on the navigation controller is presented view controller. Pop the view controller if it is, dismiss the view controller if it isn't.

```
func selectionDidFinish(viewController: UIViewController) {
    if self.navigationController?.topViewController == viewController {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    } else {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jeffery, that's pretty close. They're both tableViewControllers. I tried your both of our suggestions but the behavior is the same. Since it wasn't clear what was going on, I edited my question and examples to make it easier to understand (you were right, it wasn't as clear as it could have been). Take a look and let me know if it makes a difference.

Comment: I realized that I don't need to implement the `func selectionDidFinish(viewController:)` method in my delegate view controllers because if they conform to the protocol they'll automatically have the implementation defined in the extension. So I put your suggestion into the protocol extension and it works! Is that where you were suggesting I should put it?